# ORA-01841 :(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0 when binding to dynamic sql with DBMS_SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, dynamic-sql

When I run (snippets here):

```
t_cmd := 'begin :1 := other_package.some_function(:0,:1,:2); end;';
l_tmstmp timestamp_unconstrained := to_timestamp('1999-07-07 07:07:07.000000000',
'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9');

DBMS_SQL.PARSE(curid, t_cmd, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
-- binding here other attributes
DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(curid, ':2',  l_tmstmp);
ret := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(curid);
```

I always recieve error, even when try to bind simple timestamp, timestamp from varchar2 (TO_TIMESTAMP('timestamp_in_proper_format'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9')) :

```
ORA-01841 :(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
ORA-06512: przy linia 1
ORA-06512: przy "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1825
ORA-06512: przy "MY_PACKAGE", line where is :

ret := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(curid);
```

What is interesting problem don't occurs when I debug package.
I tried compile my package :

```
 ALTER PACKAGE my_package COMPILE DEBUG PACKAGE;
```

but problem still occurs, besides in producation environment it will be compiled with optimization level so I can't do this in that way.
Additionaly I can not use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE because function name, types and number of parameters are known at runtime.

Any idea?

Comment: I ran a simpler test case with no error.  Just this sql: "DBMS_SQL.PARSE(curs, 'select :1 from dual', DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);" and same bind parameter and data type.  Strange. Can you try that?

Comment: What is the declaration for `other_package.some_function`? I could imagine you getting this if you had timestamp (or date) and varchar2 arguments swapped, if the varchar2 value and NLS_DATE_FORMAT were suitable values. So the other values you're binding might be informative too.

Comment: thanks for your cooperation, particularly thank OldProgrammer look at the code from a different perspective - it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thank you @OldProgrammer!**
When I tried to run simple snippet as you suggested I realized something.
Problem was in this line:
    t_cmd := 'begin :1 := other_package.some_function(:0,:1,:2); end;';

I didn't change binding name from this fragment: "begin :1" and now I have two bindings to the same value. 
In execute immediate it was ok because there ORDER of bindings is significant, dbms_sql uses names of bindings.
Argument :1 from some_function(:0,:1,:2) is also timestamp.
some_function returns varchar2 so errors occured when it was trying to substitute result to first ":1".

**I changed function call to:**

```
t_cmd := 'begin :my_result := other_package.some_function(:0,:1,:2); end;';
```

**And "ORA-01841 :(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999" is gone.**

I did not focus on this fragment "begin :1 :=" because tried to get result from function like that:

```
ret := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(curid);  
src_cur := DBMS_SQL.TO_REFCURSOR(curid);
FETCH src_cur INTO my_result;  
CLOSE src_cur;
```

but this way getting result from function didn't work (some other errors occured)

Finally I changed above code to:

```
ret := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(curid);
DBMS_SQL.VARIABLE_VALUE(curid, 'my_result', my_result);  
DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(curid);
```

And now everything runs fine.